# What data structure should be used to represent this table?

Tags: data-structures

Given the following dataset.

```
|       | English | Maths | Science | Total |
|-------|---------|-------|---------|-------|
| Alice | 7       | 4     | 6       | ?     |
| Bob   | 3       | 5     | 1       | ?     |
| Total | ?       | ?     | ?       | ?     |
```

Which data structure should I represent this data with, that will allow me to calculate the values marked with question mark efficiently?

Comment: It pretty much doesn't matter. Do you need any other operations?

Comment: No. Just those values. But the dataset is really large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply keep a HashMap where key is the 'Name' and the value is the structure of 'English,Hindi... Total'. Apart from all the names in the Key, have a special Name - 'Total' in the Key. 
So, every time you are adding a student's name, lets say, Alice and subject : English, you need to search for 2 keys:
Alice and Total.

For each key, update the subject English and Total.

No need to have a complicated data structure for this. Keep it simple.

Comment: That is exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Which data structure to use depends on the context. You could store it in a relational database like PostgreSQL and calculate the values using SQL aggregate functions like `sum`.

Or you could store it as XML and use XSLT to calculate the totals.

Using programming languages you could virtually use any format you like, such as XML, JSON, YAML or CSV. The calculation is then done in the programming language of your choice using the appropriate libraries.